# excel formula with "different" columns - not just a range

Tags: excel, formula

I try to do like this:

```
=COUNTIFS($AA:$AA;$AC:$AC;$AE:$AE;$AG:$AG;$AI:$AI;"yes")<1
```

Which is of course wrong.

What I would like to do is not use a range (like $AA:$AI) but instead use every second column in the formula source.

Possible or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with the following formula:

```
{=SUM(IF(AA:AI="yes";1;0)*IF(MOD(COLUMN(AA:AI);2)=0;1;1))<1}
```

Note, that this is an array formula. So, you need to press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`. For more information on array formula read the following post: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7

The above formula counts all the occurrences of the word "yes" in the columns `AA` through `AI`. But each occurrence is furthermore multiplied with `1` or `0` depending on whether the column number can be divided by 2 without rest. Example:

Column `AA` is column 27. 27 divided by 2 equates to 13 with a remainder of 1. So, since there is a remainder, the second portion of the above formula (the second if) will return a 1 and not a 0. Hence, any occurrence of "yes" in column `AA` is accounted for. At the same time all occurrences in column `AB` will get multiplied with `0` (not accounted for). Since, I chose to use the divisor `2` all "yes" in every other column will be accounted for.

Comment: This CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER - does not give an imidate result ;-) (Office Pro Plus 2010)

Comment: I guess you haven't figured out yet, how to enter an array formula. Maybe this video can help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7bA1jdn_Fo And don't worry about your Excel version. Array formulas have always been part of Excel (even in Excel '97).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
=COUNTIF(AA:AA,"yes") + COUNTIF(AC:AC,"yes") + COUNTIF(AE:AE,"yes") + COUNTIF(AG:AG,"yes") + COUNTIF(AI:AI,"yes")
```

See image for reference:

[image]

Comment: hmm Not even =(COUNTIF(Y:Y;"yes") + COUNTIF(AA:AA;"yes") + COUNTIF(AC:AC;"yes") + COUNTIF(AE:AE;"yes") + COUNTIF(AG:AG;"yes") + COUNTIF(AI:AI;"yes")) < 1 - but the idea is good.

Comment: I tried to enclose the form in "()" and that did not work either ;-)